# How to access GKE kubectl proxy dashboard?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I would imagine the interface would have some button I could click to launch the kubectl proxy dashboard, but I could not find it.

I tried this command to get the token and entered it in:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials mycluster

kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $(kubectl -n kube-system get secret | awk '/^deployment-controller-token-/{print $1}') | awk '$1=="token:"{print $2}'

kubectl proxy
```

And it shows some things, but not others (services are missing, says it's forbidden).

How do I use kubectl proxy or show that dashboard with GKE?

Comment: It's mainly disabled by default. However most of the functionality is present in the google cloud console, e.g. the workloads/services sub-panels (and content inside)

Comment: GKE would be a great way, as you get full information about resources in the cluster.
Now, about the error, what does the full error message say? Like user "user" cant list something?

Comment: what are you doing on the second line? Out of the curiosity I ran that command and it returns a token. Why do you need it if the next command you run is `kubectl proxy`?.

Answer (score 13):

Provided you are authenticated with `gcloud auth login` and the current project and k8s cluster is configured to the one you need, authenticate `kubectl` to the cluster (this will write `~/.kube/config`):

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster name> --zone <zone> --project <project>
```

retrieve the auth token that the kubectl itself uses to authenticate as you

```
gcloud config config-helper --format=json | jq -r '.credential.access_token'
```

run

```
kubectl proxy
```

Then open a local machine web browser on

http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy
(This will only work if you checked the checkbox Deploy Dashboard in GCP console)

and use the token from the second command to log in with your Google Account's permissions.

Answer (score 5):

The Dashboard is disabled and [deprecated in GKE as of September 2017](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/dashboards). GKE provides a built in dashboard through the Management Console GUI.

Comment: Wanting us to use their tool is fine. First they make it feature complete, then they make it good. And then I'm fine with them removing the alternative by default.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable it from the Google Cloud Console (UI).

1. Edit your cluster
2. Go to "Add-ons" section
3. Find "Kubernetes dashboard"
4. Chose "disabled" from dropdown
5. Save it.

Also [according to the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/dashboards) this thing will be removed starting GKE 1.15

> Warning: The open source Kubernetes Dashboard addon is deprecated for clusters on GKE and will be removed as an option in version 1.15. It is recommended to use the alternative GCP Console dashboards described on this page.

Comment: I have enabled it but cannot find how to enter it....
I would expect to see it under Storage and Object Browser in the side menu, but cannot see in anywhere after ezploring my cluster... Any idea?

Comment: Found out. It is activated only locally by the command `kubectl proxy`. And this is not so simple. User needs to be created: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/

Also this information is summarized in some of the other answers. There is no simple solution for this....

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing, the dashboard is not deployed by default (neither in the standard Kubernetes distribution, nor as part of a GKE cluster). In order to get it up and running, you have to first [follow the instructions from the Kubernetes site](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/), summarized here:

Within the proper `kubectl` context, run the following: `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml` (nb: this url is obviously subject to change, so do check the official site to obtain the most recent version).

Then do what @Alexander outlines:

1. `gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster name> --zone <zone> --project <project>`
2. `gcloud config config-helper --format=json`
3. `kubectl proxy`

You'll be prompted for either the access token displayed in the second step or a kubeconfig file:

[image]

Pasting the access token in the field provided will gain you entry to the dashboard.